# How to add a plot to tikz with partial data from a file

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a file with points that I plot. I want to plot the points, and then plot a connecting line between the last and first point in a different color.
This is a snippet of the code I have right now, in actuality the data is in a separate file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
0 0
0 0.75
-0.3 2.2
1 1.9
1 1
1.3 0
2.2 0.2
2 1
2.1 2.3
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [mark=o, mark size=2pt, black, thick] file {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives the following picture:

[image: graph original]

I want to get the following:

[image: graph with added line]

Is there a way to get this in the code without adding another file with just the first and last points?

Comment: Unrelated: `\usepackage{filecontents}` is no longer needed in new versions of LaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can easily be done with the `skip coords between index` key by adding a second plot to the graph:

```
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{data.csv}\pgfmathsetmacro\idxend{\pgfmathresult-1}
\addplot [mark=none, mark size=2pt, red, thick, skip coords between index={1}{\idxend}] file {data.csv};
```

[image: plot]

### Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
0 0
0 0.75
-0.3 2.2
1 1.9
1 1
1.3 0
2.2 0.2
2 1
2.1 2.3
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[mark=o, mark size=2pt, black, thick] file {data.csv};
        \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{data.csv}\pgfmathsetmacro\idxend{\pgfmathresult-1}
        \addplot[mark=none, mark size=2pt, red, thick, skip coords between index={1}{\idxend}] file {data.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This requires me to know the number of data points, I don't it in advance. Is there a way to set the skip to the last point (I tried `{-1}` it didn't work) or to somehow get the number of points in the file?

Comment: @SIMEL You can use `\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{data.csv}` to get the total number of rows in a file. I've updated my answer.

Comment: +1. Great solution. No need to only show two lines - just add it all again, so others can copy and compile directly.